# Java count method for duplicate element in array List

Tags: java

say I have an array List of type Order Details

```
private static List<OrderDetails> orderDetails = new ArrayList<OrderDetails>();
```

and the fields in orderDetails are

```
    private String productCode = null;
    private int revenue = 0;
```

my arrayList contains the values`

```
A012    69
A012    36
```

I need to change the output of the list so that if something is added to the list of the same productCode the revenues get added together

so the output of the example above would be

```
A012   105
```

how will the method work

Comment: stream, collect, groupingby.

Comment: This really doesn't seem like a good use for a List, they aren't meant for deduplication - Sets and Maps are though, so probably some variant on that would be better for you. Set would still have most common Collections methods on it, so likely wouldn't need much in the way of code changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work assuming you have the appropriate `getters` for the class.  It just creates a stream of `OrderDetails` objects, filters out null productCodes and creates a map of the revenue sums.

```
Map<String,Integer> results =  orderDetails.stream()
               .filter(od->od.getProductCode() != null)
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrderDetails::getProductCode,
                Collectors.summingInt(OrderDetails::getRevenue)));
```

If desired, you can then return the values back to a list by creating a new instance of each `OrderDetails` class.

```
orderDetails = results.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e->new OrderDetails(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using a map might be more useful since you can get the revenue for any product code.

For example

```
System.out.println(results.get("A012"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The small code snippet by using a Map as below may be helpful:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

private static List<OrderDetails> orderDetails = new ArrayList<OrderDetails>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final OrderDetails o1 = new OrderDetails("A12", 69);
    final OrderDetails o2 = new OrderDetails("A12", 36);
    final OrderDetails o3 = new OrderDetails("A13", 136);
    addToList(o1);
    addToList(o2);
    addToList(o3);
    orderDetails.stream().map(orderDetail -> orderDetail.getProductCode() + " " + orderDetail.getRevenue()).forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static synchronized void addToList(OrderDetails orderDet) {
    final Map<String, OrderDetails> map = orderDetails.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(OrderDetails::getProductCode, orderDetail -> orderDetail, (a, b) -> b));
    final OrderDetails objectFromMap = map.get(orderDet.getProductCode());
    if (objectFromMap != null) {
        objectFromMap.setRevenue(objectFromMap.getRevenue() + orderDet.getRevenue());
    } else {
        map.put(orderDet.getProductCode(), orderDet);
    }
    orderDetails.clear();
    orderDetails.addAll(map.values());
}

}

class OrderDetails {
private String productCode = null;
private int revenue = 0;

public OrderDetails(String productCode, int revenue) {
    this.productCode = productCode;
    this.revenue = revenue;
}

public String getProductCode() {
    return productCode;
}

public int getRevenue() {
    return revenue;
}

public void setRevenue(int revenue) {
    this.revenue = revenue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) like this:

```java
Map<String, Integer> orderDetails = new new HashMap<>();
```

and use this method for adding a new order:

```java
    void addOrder(Order orderToAdd) {
        Order findOrder = orderDetails.get(orderToAdd.productCode);
        if (findOrder != null) {
            findOrder.revenue += orderToAdd.revenue ;
        } else {
            orderDetails.put(orderToAdd.productCode, orderToAdd.revenue );
        }
    }
```